# Populating a binary search tree with a text file

Tags: java, addition, text-files, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to fill in a binary search tree with a text file, but i'm having alot of trouble implementing my insert function. Am i reading the input correctly or is it my code?

Code for reading file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        //Checks if there is a correct number of arguments passed through the command line.
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            quitError("Tree command word arguments expected");
        } 

        String inputFile = args[0];
        BST btree = new BST();  

        try
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

            //Scans each word from the input and prints it out
            String word = input.readLine();
            while (word != null)
            {
                btree.insert(word);
                word = input.readLine();
            }
            return;

        } catch(FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexception) //Catches file not found exception
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioexception) //Catches input/output exception
        {
            System.out.println("File input error occured!");
        }

    }

    //Displays an error message, program exits
    public static void quitError(String msg)
    {
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println("Program will now quit.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Code for the binary search tree node:

```
public class BSTNode {
    protected String data;
    protected BSTNode left, right;

    public BSTNode() 
    {
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public BSTNode(String data)
    {
        this(data,null,null);
    }

    public BSTNode(String data, BSTNode lt, BSTNode rt) 
    {
        this.data = data; 
        left = lt; 
        right = rt;
    }
}
```

Code for the binary search tree:

```
public class BST {
    protected BSTNode root = null;
    public BST(){}

    public void clear()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return root == null;
    }


    public void insert(String data) 
    {
BSTNode p = root, prev = null;
    while (p != null) {
        prev = p;
        if (p.data.compareTo(data) < 0)
            p = p.right;
        else p = p.left;
    }
    if (root == null)
        root = new BSTNode(data);
    else if (prev.data.compareTo(data) < 0)
        prev.right = new BSTNode(data);
    else prev.left  = new BSTNode(data);
    }   

    public void inorder()
    {
        inorder(root);
    }

    private void inorder(BSTNode p) 
    {
        if (p != null) 
        {
            inorder(p.left);
            System.out.print(p.data + " ");
            inorder(p.right);
        }
    }

    public void breadthFirst() 
    {
        BSTNode p = root;
        Queue queue = new Queue();
        if (p != null) 
        {
            queue.enqueue(p);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) 
            {
                p = (BSTNode) queue.dequeue();
                System.out.print(p.data + " ");
                if (p.left != null)
                    queue.enqueue(p.left);
                if (p.right != null)
                    queue.enqueue(p.right);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the file has one word per line, you're going to have trouble.  The buffered reader is giving you the entire line.  Is it a word or a sentence?

Your insert() method is empty.  Nothing will happen without that.  Put some code into it and you may have better luck.

So it seems to me you have two problems:

1. Your input is incorrect unless it's one word per line.  If each line is a sentence, you'll have to tokenize it into words.
2. Your insert method does nothing.  No wonder your tree isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally removed my insert code.
Here is the code:

public void insert(String data) 
 {
        BSTNode p = root, prev = null;
        while (p != null) {
            prev = p;
            if (p.data.compareTo(data) < 0)
                 p = p.right;
            else p = p.left;
        }
        if (root == null)
             root = new BSTNode(data);
        else if (prev.data.compareTo(data) < 0)
             prev.right = new BSTNode(data);
        else prev.left  = new BSTNode(data);
 }

Comment: I can only comment on what I see.

Comment: Put it back into you question.  It's illegible here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
String word = input.readLine();
```

with

```
String word = input.read();
```

This should work